# Prettyphoto lightbox on responsive site

Tags: php, jquery, lightbox

I'm hoping someone will be able to offer an insight into where I'm going wrong with a site I've been working on lately - the issue I'm having is with the prettyphoto lightbox. Works fine in every browser other than IE and iPhone/IOS browsers. On those, the lightbox loader spins and then stalls. I've tried to find the issue, but struggling, so any help would be much appreciated.

The site is http://auction-direct.local-creative.co.uk/ and the lightbox images are on the prize lots page.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you include your code in the question.

Comment: Hi fresh, thanks for the tip- though i'm not sure what code would be of use as i don't know exactly what is broken, so i though someone viewing the source may have an inkling to suggest which code they would need to see?

Answer (score 0):

This lightbox loader works fine in IE11. However I did find an issue in IE8 when I used the emulation setting in IE11's developer tools.

On line 203 in jquery.prettyPhoto.js there is a call to:

```
console.log(desText);
```

However, console output only works if you have the [console or script tabs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx) open; if they are not an error is raised. The code should guard against this problem by checking to see whether console is available:

```
if (typeof console != "undefined") { 
 console.log(desText); 
}
```

Hence I suggest modifying jquery.prettyPhoto.js to fix this bug. It is questionable whether this console output is necessary in this library anyway.

Hopefully this *might* fix your issue. The author of jquery.prettyPhoto.js also has a forum on their website, so I also suggest you posting this issue there too.